# Error while intergrating mdbootstrap into angular project

Tags: angular, mdbootstrap

I tried to add material design to my angular project .I included the lines

```
"scripts": [

  "../node_modules/hammer.js/hammer.min.js"
    ]
```

and then i got the following errors:-

**92% additional asset processing scripts-webpack-plugin✖ ｢wdm｣: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/ratnabhkumarrai/Desktop/Angular practice/node_modules/hammer.js/hammer.min.js'**

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to including hammerjs. Either simply, import `hammerjs` in your `src/main.ts` file per the Angular Material [getting starting documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-5-gesture-support):

```
import 'hammerjs';
```

Or update your path if you are adding it in `scripts` of the @angular/cli configuration as `hammerjs` resides in a node_modules directory named `hammerjs`, not `hammer.js` (no `.` character between `hammer` and `js`):

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
]
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Care to comment why the downvote? This was taken directly from the getting started documentation as well as @angular/cli global lib documentation. They got the error no such directory exactly because doing `npm install --save hammerjs` creates a folder named `hammerjs`, not `hammer.js` as the OP attempted.